# Does IOM provide accomodation for asylum seekers in Cuba?

Tags: accommodation, asylum, cuba

A friend of mine needs to get out of the country and is going to Cuba. His destination is Canada to receive asylum. He is going to run his case in IOM in Cuba. All he is worried about is how long will it take for him to get his case approval and if IOM provides accommodation for him there?

Edit: [IOM is International Organization for Migration](http://costarica.iom.int/en/cuba/mission_more_information/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a problem faced by expats